# dynamodb query im trying to get some data from dynamodb using laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, laravel-4.2, amazon-dynamodb-index

the query is work now but the problem is the `attribute_not_exists` when I added the attribute_not_exists the whole query not working.

error message: "One or more parameter values were invalid: Secondary (truncated...)
 ValidationException (client): One or more parameter values were invalid: Secondary index status-created_at-index does not project one or more filter attributes: [affiliate, agent, partner]"

[image]

Can some explain why? Thank you, I'm a newbie

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set projections for these three attributes (affiliate, agent, partner), when you created the secondary index.

You can see it in the output you've got:

`Secondary index status-created_at-index does not project one or more filter attributes: [affiliate, agent, partner]`

A projection is the set of attributes that is copied from a table into a secondary index. The partition key and sort key of the table are always projected into the index; **you can** project **other attributes** to support your application's query requirements.

You can learn more about this in [Amazon DynamoDB Global Secondary Index Attribute Projections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Projections).

Comment: Thank you it helped me